# How to loop through additional pages using google places and javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-places-api

I am building a single page application and am using the frontend javascript API to access google maps and places. I am successfully able to generate a google map and get the establishments details through this api, however, the javascript API does not return a "next_page_token" that allows me to search for additional results after the first 20.

How do you use the javascript API to get the next_page_token to loop through multiple pages of results? I am desperate since I can't find any information about this anywhere.

**Edit - Including some additional info.**

Doing a nearbySearch using the documentation [provided by Google here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search) simply returns a set of 20 results with no additional properties in the response.

Here is the request I am making using Javascript API. I have the script included on my index.html file.

```
let map = new google.maps.Map(this.$refs.map, {
    center: this.location,
    zoom: 12,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    scrollwheel: false
})

let request = {
    location: this.location,
  radius: 10000,
  type: ['restaurants'] 
}

let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
    console.log("Results", results)
    console.log("Status", status)
})
```

Here is what google is sending back. Taking from console in devtools.

```
Results (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Results from nearbySearch request third argument.

```
a4 {f: ƒ, b: ƒ, l: "CqQCIAEAAPcNpixD40jA39VnP-WMOZT21nGCcfpK_smpYhG66W…UWk72OjPB1A7Mdudz6UhoUD_vqC-QSk7CKnoveUXK0IHnQ8es", j: 1528768999850, hasNextPage: true}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at [the doc page for "nearbySearch"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) and this example sticks out:

```
// Perform a nearby search.
  service.nearbySearch(
      {location: pyrmont, radius: 500, type: ['store']},
      function(results, status, pagination) {
        if (status !== 'OK') return;

        createMarkers(results);
        moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
        getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
          pagination.nextPage();
        };
      });
```

because notice the callback takes a third parameter that is used to fetch additional results.

Comment: I did notice there was a third argument, but the third argument does not contain any labeled token or next page. There is a property labelled "l" which has a long hash like value, and I tried passing that as nextpagetoken which didn't work. It was ignored or passed the same results back. I till try copying this example verbatim shortly and see if that works for me. I have updated my question with what is returned from the third argument.

Answer (score 3):

**From the google page search API**

Accessing Additional Results:

> By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20
>   establishment results per query; however, each search can return as
>   many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will
>   return more than 20, then the search response will include an
>   additional value — next_page_token. Pass the value of the
>   next_page_token to the pagetoken parameter of a new search to see the
>   next set of results. If the next_page_token is null, or is not
>   returned, then there are no further results. There is a short delay
>   between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become
>   valid. Requesting the next page before it is available will return an
>   INVALID_REQUEST response. Retrying the request with the same
>   next_page_token will return the next page of results

So in short in the response from a call like:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=YOUR_API_KEY

-OR-

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&type=food&key=YOUR_API_KEY

You will find:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCAgEAAFxg8o-eU7_uKn7Yqjana-HQIx1hr5BrT4zBaEko29ANsXtp9mrqN0yrKWhf-y2PUpHRLQb1GT-mtxNcXou8TwkXhi1Jbk-ReY7oulyuvKSQrw1lgJElggGlo0d6indiH1U-tDwquw4tU_UXoQ_sj8OBo8XBUuWjuuFShqmLMP-0W59Vr6CaXdLrF8M3wFR4dUUhSf5UC4QCLaOMVP92lyh0OdtF_m_9Dt7lz-Wniod9zDrHeDsz_by570K3jL1VuDKTl_U1cJ0mzz_zDHGfOUf7VU1kVIs1WnM9SGvnm8YZURLTtMLMWx8-doGUE56Af_VfKjGDYW361OOIj9GmkyCFtaoCmTMIr5kgyeUSnB-IEhDlzujVrV6O9Mt7N4DagR6RGhT3g1viYLS4kO5YindU6dm3GIof1Q",
   "results" : [{...}]
}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: A next_page_token will not be returned if there are no additional results to display. The maximum number of results that can be returned is 60. There is a short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become valid.

Read more:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. 

I did see this information, however, the next_page_token is not issued. I know 100% from doing searches on google that there are more than 20 results, more than 60.
I don't think the examples used there are for the Javascript API. They CAN be called from Ajax but they return cors errors. I have been trying to do this from the javascript library due to restrictions of working with SPA.

Comment: I just realized, this means even if there are more than 60 results there will only be a maximum of 60 results returned.